# View FadeTo not fading in Android API 22

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm working in Xamarin both iOS and Android. I'm trying to fade in the logo of my application slowly with 5000 milliseconds delay from 0 to 1. It seems that `FadeTo()` function works perfectly fine on my phone with API 26. However, when I try to run the same function in another phone with API 22, the view that I'm trying to fade in doesn't fade. The image/logo just appears right after the app is ready to run. Take note, the time needed to prepare the app to run (the greyish-white screen) does not count up to 5 seconds. It sometimes go between 2-4 seconds. Either way, I need to know how to fix this fading bug.

So in my SplashScreen.xaml, this contains the `Image`, called `logo`, that I want to fade in. here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ProjectName.SplashScreenPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
            <Image x:Name="logo"
                   Source="logo"
                   HorizontalOptions ="CenterAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   Opacity="0"
                   Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In the `SplashScreen.cs`, which contains the code for the Image `logo` to fade in is in this file. There's code only in the constructor. Thus, I'm only going to copy the constructor. The code for the `SplashScreen.cs` file is:

```
public SplashScreenPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
         ViewExtensions.FadeTo(logo, 1, 5000, Easing.Linear);
    });
}
```

I haven't touched any other code besides these two files. The `AndroidManifest.xml` file contains this section pertaining to API level which is:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="22" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
```

Let me know if there is info I need to add